# Getting indices of distinct value in an array for each document

Tags: mongodb

I've installed MongoDB and started testing it. I am new to MongoDB and trying to learn it. I have created a collection with the following items:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fb60945df88631311ab8a48"), "name" : "x-market", "tags" : ["water", "soda", "water"] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fb60945df88631311ab8a49"), "name" : "y-market", "tags" : ["juice", "water"] }
```

What I'd like to do is query so I get, for each tag/document, 1 document having the name of the document and the tag with an array of indices of the tag in the tags array. It is complicated but the result should look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId, "name" : "x-market", "tag" : "water", index = [0,2]}
{ "_id" : ObjectId, "name" : "x-market", "tag" : "soda", index = [1]}
{ "_id" : ObjectId, "name" : "y-market", "tag" : "juice", index = [0]}
{ "_id" : ObjectId, "name" : "y-market", "tag" : "water", index = [1]}
```

How do I query for this? I tried to use `$group, $project $reduce` operators but I got lost and my query is failing to execute. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `tags` array and add arrayindex in `index` key
- `$group` by `name` and `tags`, push `index` in index array, get first `name`
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$tags",
      includeArrayIndex: "index"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        tags: "$tags"
      },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      index: { $push: "$index" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      name: "$name",
      tag: "$_id.tags",
      index: "$index"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Od3iQ2nOc30)

Comment: this is great. thank you! do you have any tip to give if I want to exclude "soda" from search before querying?

Comment: You can use $map, $cond and $$REMOVE, in first stage $set, just try and let me know will help further.

Comment: I solved that by adding this query before $unwind: $set: {
      "tags": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$tags",
          as: "tag",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$tag",
              "soda"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }